# Conditionally disabling a Bootstrap control

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to enable or disable a control based on a value from a model. I was hoping I could use `disabled="disabled"` when I want the control to be disabled, or else, `disabled = ""` when I want it to work.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountTypeId, Model.AccountTypes, "Select One", new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = Model.ClosedDate.HasValue ? "disabled" : "" })
```

But this doesn't work, and the control is always disabled, regardless of the value. Is there a way I can do this, without using JavaScript or something?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the way the `disabled` attribute works in HTML is if present on an element, regardless of value, it marks the element as disabled.

So, you could modify your code to something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AccountTypeId, Model.AccountTypes, "Select One", (Model.ClosedDate.HasValue ? new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } : new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Not the prettiest but should get the job done

Comment: Thanks. So there's no 'clean' way to disable a control? What pattern would be more acceptable? I'm guessing that maybe displaying a label, instead of the control, based on the 'ClosedDate' in my case, would be another way? But then, you lose the posted value.

Answer (score 1):

One more point to remember is the fact that setting the input as disabled prevent the form to submit the value of the input, and you might get into some trouble when the mvc bind your model, because they will insert default values for the property disabled. If you want to post the value back to your controller, use readonly attribute instead of disabled.